How to identify the location of a message in Outlook's search results?
I'm using Microsoft Outlook to search for messages based on sender, keyword, etc., but the search results do not include a "Folder" column.

In older versions of Outlook (Classic Outlook), there was an Advanced Find dialog accessed using Ctrl+Shift+F that showed the location of messages in search results as a tooltip when hovering over them. This functionality doesn't appear supported in New Outlook.

In Outlook on the web, a message's location is listed within the search results:



How can I determine the location of messages in search results?
Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO
Version 2402, Build 16.0.17328.20282, 64-bit
Microsoft 365 apps for Enterprise


That was unnecessary and incredibly generous.  Thank you!

Identifying location from search results
In Microsoft Outlook there are multiple approaches to identify the location (folder) of messages returned by search.
These include:

Checking if it's already displayed but missed because it's combined in another column.
Reviewing message properties
Adding the In Folder column using either   a)  Add Columns   b)  Manage Views

1.  Location may already be displayed in results
In this example, the location is listed below the date.

2.  Retrieving location from message properties
To access message properties,

Select the message then Alt+Enter


3a.  Use 'Add Columns' to include location

Navigate to View > Add Columns (varies slightly based on Ribbon, see images)
Alt+V then 00C  (zero-zero-c)    
Select In Folder from the All Mail fields and click Add -> then OK
Tip: Long sorted list, so typing I jumps to the i's, avoiding excessive scrolling 

3b.  Use 'Change View' to include location
Using the Add Folders option above (3a.) is quicker but you can achieve the same by changing the View

Navigate to View > Change View > Manage Views
Alt+V then CVM 
In the Manage All Views dialog select Modify
Alt+M
  
In the Advanced View Settings dialog, click Columns
Alt+C 
Select In Folder from the All Mail fields and click Add -> then OKThis step is identical to step 3a.2 (which includes images)

